# Zend Server contains Apache in it?

Tags: php, zend-server

I am little confused with zend server and Apache server. What is the difference? When i installed it in my windows system. It contains Apache folder in it. What is the main different? Does apache work internally in the zendServer?

Comment: ``Zend Server`` is a installation package and ``Apache`` is web server. when ``Zend server `` installed,  Apache n Mysql will be configured along with ``Zend Framework``.

Comment: So it is apache which is running in background not the ZendServer? And ZendServer is just the installation package..Thanks. @Sameer K

Answer (score 1):

[Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend_server) comes with the Apache, but you can also use IIS if you want. It also comes with MySQL for that matter so it provides a full wamp/wimp install. On Linux you can use apache (from the distro) or nginx (only from [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/)).

So Zend Server itself provides the PHP part plus all the other cool things like Z-Ray, caching, clustering and so on. Zend Server hooks into the webserver.

Comment: I want the flow. When request send to the server which one accepts the request apache or ZendServer.@roheim

Comment: User -> Apache -> Zend Server -> DB -> Zend Server -> Apache -> User

Comment: User -> Apache -> Zend Server or Zend Engine? -> DB ->  Zend Server or Zend Engine? -> Apache -> User @roheim

Comment: Zend Engine is in PHP.